# Не работает php7 сервер nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php7

При попытке открыть сайт "502 Bad Gateway"

Изначально в логах была ошибка:

```
var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock: no such file or directory
```

Потом после нескольких попыток исправить, новая ошибка:

```
2016/06/08 12:29:00 [error] 8299#0: *19 connect() failed
(111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 434.445.553.526,
server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com"
```

В настройках хоста:

```
location ~ .php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    astcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Как это поправить?

Конфиг:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix (/usr). This prefix can be dynamically changed by using the
; '-p' argument from the command line.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: none
pid = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; in a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /var/log/php7.0-fpm.log

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; The maximum number of processes FPM will fork. This has been design to control
; the global number of processes when using dynamic PM within a lot of pools.
; Use it with caution.
; Note: A value of 0 indicates no limit
; Default Value: 0
; process.max = 128

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the master process (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lower priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool process will inherit the master process priority
;         unless it specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
; process.priority = -19

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

; Set open file descriptor rlimit for the master process.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; - kqueue     (FreeBSD >= 4.1, OpenBSD >= 2.9, NetBSD >= 2.0)
; - /dev/poll  (Solaris >= 7)
; - port       (Solaris >= 10)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
;events.mechanism = epoll

; When FPM is build with systemd integration, specify the interval,
; in second, between health report notification to systemd.
; Set to 0 to disable.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default value: 10
;systemd_interval = 10

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Multiple pools of child processes may be started with different listening
; ports and different management options.  The name of the pool will be
; used in logs and stats. There is no limitation on the number of pools which
; FPM can handle. Your system will tell you anyway :)

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
; Relative path can also be used. They will be prefixed by:
;  - the global prefix if it's been set (-p argument)
;  - /usr otherwise
include=/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

По порту 9000 ничего нет

```
lsof -i :9000
```

**ps aux | grep php**

[image: ps aux | grep php]

Comment: 1. *127.0.0.1:9000* — этот порт кто-то слушает/отвечает? 2. приведите и настройки *php-fpm*. 3. директиву *fastcgi_pass*, вероятно, лучше всё-таки указывать **после** всех остальных директив, а не **до**. 4. *astcgi_param* — опечатка.

Comment: Проверьте запущен ли php-fpm при помощи команды ps aux | grep php

Comment: @cheops приложил скрин

Comment: @SomethingWhoNeedHelp, спасибо. Да php-fpm на месте.

Comment: `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/*.conf` — в этих файлах должно быть указано что слушает PHP

Comment: @alexanderbarakin порядок разных директив fastcgi неважен.

Comment: @AlexeyTen http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1465491928.png я закомментил строчку, ранее была ошибка  `var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock: no such file or directory`

Comment: Ну так в закомментированной строчке нет никакого `/var`.

Comment: Вы перезапустили PHP-FPM после изменения конфигурации?

Comment: @AlexeyTen перезапускал... как сделать правильно? может снести php-fpm? И правильно установить, только как) Локально все работает, на сервере какая-то беда